# jquery generic select code - how

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I need to do this:

```
$("#textarea1").mouseup(function () {
    // how to catch the "1" and set it inside inner selectors?
    $('#id_generator_textbox1_x').val(Math.round($(this).position().left));
    $('#id_generator_textbox1_y').val(Math.round($(this).position().top));
    $('#id_generator_textbox1_w').val($(this).width());
    $('#id_generator_textbox1_h').val($(this).height());
});
```

multiple times. the `textarea1` can be `textarea2` etc .. the same for inner selectors.

how can I make it select genericly without repeating this code 10 times?

Comment: How about posting the HTML you want to use this on?

Comment: What about a common class for all the items?

Comment: @LelioFaieta it cannot be classes, since each item can have different values

Comment: Then you can't select all of them together. Even in a for loop you would need a switch statement for all the alternatives.

Comment: @LelioFaieta sure? what about regexp ?

Comment: You would add a layer of complication to the readability of the code without adding performance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("[id^='textarea']").mouseup(function () {
    var idSelector = '#id_generator_' + this.id.replace('textarea','textbox');
    $(idSelector + '_x').val(Math.round($(this).position().left));
    $(idSelector + '_y').val(Math.round($(this).position().top));
    $(idSelector + '_w').val($(this).width());
    $(idSelector + '_h').val($(this).height());
});
```